# querying 3500 entry using getResults in symfony2/doctrine is slow

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My time to first byte (TTFB) in my homepage of my website is around 1.8 second, which is pretty slow knowing that the best practice should be 500ms. I've been using the debug tool and it seems that most of the times is spent on the controller, specifically I have a query that pulls around 3500 entity, which doesn't seem too significant. I have been using the debug tool and tested this in prod version as well, however it is still slow in prod version. Here's the query:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$picturesQuery = $qb->select('DISTINCT p')
        ->from("AppMainBundle:ShopPicture", 'p')
                    ->innerJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
                    ->addOrderBy('p.numberoflikes', 'DESC')
                    ;

            //if this is not admin, then do not show locked stores
            if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
                $picturesQuery->andWhere('shop.isLocked  = :isLocked')  
                              ->setParameter('isLocked', 0);

                $picturesQuery->andWhere('p.isLocked = :pictureLocked')
                              ->setParameter('pictureLocked', 0)
                              ;
            } 

            $query = $picturesQuery->getQuery();
            $query->useResultCache(true, 3600);
            $shopPictures = $query->getResult();
```

I've been using doctrine2 results query with memcached, but it seems that it didn't help. Querying the database actually only takes around 50 ms, which is nothing. Here's the full profiling info (if you can't see it here's the [full image](http://cl.ly/image/0u1g3I1V0B2d)):

[image]

If I comment out the  `$query->getResult();` then it drops to about 300-400 ms. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the raw query on your DB and see how it performed there?

Comment: Commenting `$query->getResult();` skips the actual fetching of the records.

Comment: Furthermore if the results are hydrated as objects, the hydration can be slow as @Lumbendil pointed out. Try hydrating the results as an array to see if the time, to get the results, changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained on IRC, you should paginate the $query, not the $shopPictures.

Object hydration of 3500 objects is slow :)

EDIT: For anyone reading the comment. The missing part here is that the results where paginated. The issue with how it's written now is that it fetches all the results, only to display a handful of them.